# QWidget setFocus does nothing

Tags: c++, qt, focus

I am implementing a custom context menu that is basically a widget called `gripmenu` containing several other widgets. If the user left clicks, this menu should appear. To hide or delete it if the user clicks outside of it, I need to somehow check if the user click somewhere else. My plan is to ask all its child widgets for `->hasFocus()` and if none hasFocus, I will close the menu. But unfortunately I can't set the focus. Why? My code is:

```
gripmenu = new GripMenu(this);
gripmenu->setFocus();
```

And in the `gripmenu`'s constructor:

```
GripMenu::GripMenu(){
  [... set things up]
  ui->lineEdit->setFocus(); // or any other widget to focus, 
                            // even this->setFocus() does not work: see below:
  qDebug() << ui->lineEdit->hasFocus(); // returns false!
}
```

How is it possible that there is no focus immediately after I just set it?

At the end my goal is to mimic a typical context-menu behaviour (meaning that the menu is closed when clicked somewhere else). So if you have better suggestions on how to tackle it, please hint me that way!

EDIT:

I got it working. The hint of Frank Osterfeld was really useful. Still I had to add a "gripmenu->activate()" in the widget "A" that created(needed) the gripmenu, because without it, the active widget would still be "A" after the mouse got released.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus says "Be aware that if the widget is hidden, it will not accept focus until it is shown."

Comment: or if you just use customContextMenu it will do this for you...have you looked at this?

Comment: I don't think I could insert such a complex widget as a `QWidgetAction*` into a `QMenu`, but thanks

Comment: @user2366975 it's QAction, not QWidget. QMenu is MEANT to contain QActions. The whole purpose of polymorphic design.

Answer (score 5):

Try the code below, it  should work:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, lineEdit, SLOT(setFocus()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Widget normally won't be shown, redrawn or get focus immediately, so synchronous call is useless.

Why don't you use `QWidgetAction` to embed widgets into a normal menu instead of hacking through signal handling?